# Output called inside conditionalPanel keeps being called even when hidden

Tags: r, shiny

I have an inputdate on the header of my shinyapp, and I want the tabpanels to appear and the outputs to be called only when a working days is selected. The reason why I need that is because some of my outputs have to do big queries and take a lot of time.

So I've created an output$check_refdate that checks if the date selected is valid, and used it in conditionalPanels inside each tab. But what I've realised is that my outputs are called even after they are hidden (at least at first: if I pick two holidays, one after the other, the output is triggered at the first holiday but not the second). I tried explicitly setting the suspendWhenHidden to TRUE, but the output keeps being called...

Here is a small example:

```
## global
library(shiny)
library(DT) 
# add ANBIMA holidays
library(lubridate)
library(bizdays)
.calendar <- bizdays::Calendar(holidaysANBIMA, weekdays=c('saturday', 'sunday'), dib=252, name='ANBIMA')
bizdays::bizdays.options$set(default.calendar=.calendar)


## ui
shinyUI(
navbarPage(
title = 'Testing Hidden Output', 
header =
   fluidRow(
      inputPanel(
         div('Data de Referência: ', style = "font-size:18px"), 
         dateInput("refdate", label = NULL, value = Sys.Date()),
         align = 'center'
      ),
      htmlOutput("check_header")
   ),

   tabPanel('test',
      conditionalPanel(
         condition = "!output.check_header",
         column(4, plotOutput("plotdata"))
      )
   ) 
 )
)

## server
shinyServer (function(input, output, session) {
   cdata <- session$clientData

   checkrefdate <- reactive({ 
     print('checking refdate')
     if(input$refdate == adjust.previous(input$refdate)) return(NULL)
     tags$h1('Choose a bizdays day!', align = 'center', 
         style = 'color: red; padding-top: 5%;')
     })
     output$check_header <- renderUI({ checkrefdate() })

     selectData <- reactive( x <- 1:10 )
     output$plotdata <- renderPlot({ 
       # if suspendWhenHidden=T, should never print on console "plotdata:  TRUE ", right?
       cat('plotdata_hidden: ', cdata[['output_plotdata_hidden']], '\n') 
       plot(selectData(), main = '') 
     })
     outputOptions(output, 'plotdata', suspendWhenHidden = T)
  })
```

Thanks